# How to add Blazor components to body via code?

Tags: blazor

I would like to do something like this:

```
private async Task buttonClick()
{
    var comp1 = new MyComp();
    comp1.Opt = new MyOpt { ... };        

    // add comp1 to body (or a div) here
    // in jQuery I would do $('#div1').append(comp1);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? That's not how SPAs like Blazor and React work. Blazor is React# more-or-less. Instead of modifying the DOM at runtime, you define components, data binding and state and let the SPA framework modify only the changed DOM elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blazor doesn't support `new MyComp();`, instantiation is left to the renderer.

It is much simpler:

```
@if(showComp1)
{
   <Component1 />
}

@code
{
  bool showComp;

  private void ButtonClick()
  {
    showComp = true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MWE (Minimum Working Example) for what you are trying to accomplish.

When the property is updated in the button handler the MWEIndex component is updated al well showing MyComp.

file Pages/MyComp.razor

```
<h1>MyComp</h1
```

file Pages/MWEIndex.razor

```
@page "/mwe"

<button @onclick="buttonClick">Toggle MyComp</button>
<div>
@if(this.ShowMyComp)
{
  <MyComp />  
}
</div>

@code
{
  public bool ShowMyComp { get; set; } = false;

  private void buttonClick(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    this.ShowMyComp = !this.ShowMyComp;
  }
}
```